# Methods:println() and write() in java

Tags: java, servlets

Hello,

I want to know the difference between `println()` and `write()` methods used in java servlet.

```
out.println("Hello");
out.write("Hello");
```

How the above code will be stored??
Why can we use both the methods for the writing the same text as above..

Comment: Can you modify your question so that you explicitly give the type of out? It will help others reading your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the exact difference between out.write() and out.print()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338134/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-out-write-and-out-print)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

1.**out.write("")** method is for java.io.Writer it is used to write the any file like text,csv.

2.**out.println("Hello")** this one is servlet method and it is use for write data on browser.

Comment: Are you mad. Have you ever seen the API of java.lang.System class.

Comment: Actually i understand the question as different.I understand he is asking about java write method and servlet method thats why i wrote this.

Comment: it's nothing to with servlet as such.

Comment: Ya i got it now.But you can see the questionar tag the java and servlet so you tell what people understand.you know this also used in servlet.

Comment: Thanks everyone..for the response

Comment: I am newbie of servlet java programming. So,i am confused in some books it is mentioned with the out object the println() method and in others i found with the out object is write() method. So,when to use which method i am little bit confused..So,with context to servlet i am asking when we can use write method and when to use println() methods???

Comment: I hope u got the difference between 2 what i want to say.http://www.jsptutorial.net/writing-the-first-java-servlet.aspx that expalaing out.println and other one just they used method in java http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jebp_3/index1.html?page=2

Answer (score 5):

The `out` variable in your case is most likely refers to a `PrintWriter`, so the answer to your question lies in the [API documentation of that class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

Just compare the description of `write`...

> `public void write(String s)`
>
> Write a string. This method cannot be inherited from the Writer class because it must suppress I/O exceptions.

... with the description of `println` ...

> `public void println(String x)`
>
> Print a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

... and `print` ...

> `public void print(String s)`
>
> Print a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

All in all I'd say that the `print` methods work on a **higher level of abstraction** and is the one I prefer to work with when writing servlets.

Answer (score 0):

The only plausible difference with  `PrintWriter.println` has to with flushing which is invoked in case of using `println` but not `print("\n")` in all other respects it would behave same as `print()`

Plus the `PrintWriter` class also doent throw any Exception.