# What is the exact difference between out.write() and out.print()

Tags: java, servlets, printwriter

In my servlet I gave both `out.print` and `out.write`. but both prints in the browser.

What is the exact difference between these two and when to use `out.print` and `out.write` ?

Comment: What's the type of `out`? What do the docs say?

Comment: In servlets, `out` is a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

Answer (score 18):

The short answer is that `out.write()` explodes if you pass it a null:

```
String s = null;
out.print(s); // outputs the text "null"
out.write(s); // NullPointerException
```

The more complete answer is that `out` in servlets is a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html) whose overloaded `write()` methods only accept a few basic types but do the work of outputting bytes to the underlying `OutputStream`.

The `print()` method is a convenience wrapper method that wraps calls to `write()` to provide custom behaviour for its numerous overloaded implementations. For example:

```
public void print(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = "null";
    }
    write(s);
} 

public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}

public void print(double d) {
    write(String.valueOf(d));
}
```

etc for all the primitive types.

Comment: Is this really the main difference that should be remembered and determine the use of those two methods?

Comment: @vaclav In servlets, `out` is a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html) whose `write()` methods do the work of outputting and whose `print()` methods are convenience wrappers for `write()` overloaded to accept a wide range of types - see edited answer.

Answer (score 12):

There are three major differences:

1) If you try to print a null value of a String with **out.write()** , It will throw **NullPointerException** while **out.print()** will simply print **NULL** as a string.

```
 String name = null;
 out.write(name); // NullPointerException
 out.print(name); // 'Null' as text will be printed
```

2) **out.print()** can print Boolean values but **out.write()** can not.

```
boolean b = true;
out.write(b); // Compilation error
out.print(b); // 'true' will be printed
```

3) If you are using **out.write()**, you simply can not place arithmetic operation code but **out.print()** provides the support.

```
out.write(10+20); // No output will be displayed.
out.print(10+20); // Output '30' will be displayed.
```

Comment: ad 3) I suppose that write(10+20) just writes character 30 - i.e. "Record Separator" to the stream. Thus the note about arithmetic operations does not have sense.

Answer (score 10):

[PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

> public void write(String s)
>
> Write a string. This method cannot be inherited from the Writer class
>   because it must suppress I/O exceptions.

**print method has higher level of abstraction.**

> public void print(String s)
>
> Print a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is
>   printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes
>   according to the platform's default character encoding, and these
>   bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The out variable in your case is most likely refers to a PrintWriter

Just compare the description of write...

> `public void write(String s)`
>
> Write a string. This method cannot be inherited from the Writer class because it must suppress I/O exceptions.

... with the description of println ...

> `public void println(String x)`
>
> Print a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

... and print ...

> `public void print(String s)`
>
> Print a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

All in all I'd say that the print methods work on a higher level of abstraction and is the one I prefer to work with when writing servlets.

Answer (score 2):

`PrintWriter`'s implementation communicates the difference better than javadoc

```
public void print(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = "null";
    }
    write(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing is you can't use `javax.​servlet.​jsp.​JspWriter out` in a servlet. It has to be used in a `.jsp` file, because `out` is a method local variable in `_jspService(...)` method of your `.jsp` file.

> There is no difference in the purpose of using `out.print()` and `out.write()`. **Both are used to write the `String` version of the given object to JspWriter's buffer.**

However, `JspWriter.print()` is capable of taking many types of arguments than `Writer.write()`.

**`JspWriter.print()`**

- Object
- String
- boolean
- char
- char[]
- double
- float
- int
- long

**`Writer.write()`**

- String
- char
- int

Answer (score 1):

write() method only writes characters to stream(or console) but does not print, while print() method writes and print it on stream (or console).

```
System.out.write(97);
System.out.print('j');
```

first statement writes character 97 i.e 'a' on console but does not print, while second statement prints 'a' which is written already on stream and 'j' which is passed in print() method.

Comment: So where the written data goes to?

Comment: It remains into stream until stream does not flush, after flushing stream data will print on console. print() method flush previous data and print the data passed into it.

Comment: Thus the print methods do the flushing automatically? Doesn't it depend on the PrintWriter setup?

Answer (score 1):

I simply know it as like this:

`out.println()` is method of `javax.​servlet.​jsp.​JspWriter`

`out.write()` is method of `java.io.Writer`

Answer (score -1):

## out.write(-) vs out.print(-)

**One more difference is out.write(-)**
method just write data or object to browser like a file. You can not write any statement like **out.write(10*20);** but we do this with **out.print(10*20);**