# PrintWriter write() vs print() method in Java

Tags: java, file

What is the difference between `write()` and `print()` methods in `PrintWriter` class in Java?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/398792/java/java/write-print

Comment: I guess there is not much difference, as behind the scene `print()` method calls `write()` method. For example: `public void print(int i) { write(String.valueOf(i)); }`

Comment: @Kartic - You guessed wrong :-)  The `valueOf` call is *formatting* the integer.  With `write(int)` you are writing a character represented as an `int`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> print() formats the output, while write() just prints the characters
>   it is given. print() handles many argument types, converting them into
>   printable strings of characters with String.valueOf(), while write()
>   just handles single characters, arrays of characters, and strings.
>
> To illustrate the difference, write(int) interprets the argument as a
>   single character to be printed, while print(int) converts the integer
>   into a character string. write(49) prints a "1", while print(49)
>   prints "49".

source: http://www.coderanch.com/t/398792/java/java/write-print

Answer (score 4):

`write(int)` writes a single character (hence takes the Unicode character of the passed `int`).

`print(datatype)` on the other hand converts the datatype (`int`, `char`, etc)  to a String by first calling `String.valueOf(int)` or `String.valueOf(char)` which is translated into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

For more details, you can refer the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) of `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 2):

> print() formats the output, while write() just prints the characters
>   it is given. print() handles many argument types

According to [coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/174675/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/print-write-PrintWriter) and [this one too](http://www.coderanch.com/t/398792/java/java/write-print)

Answer (score 2):

write() is supposed to be used when you need to just print characters while print() is supported to be used when you need to format character output.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void write(String s)
```

Write a string. This method cannot be inherited from the Writer class because it must suppress I/O exceptions.supports only int and String as parameters

print method has higher level of abstraction.

```
public void print(String s)
```

Print a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.supports all primitive data types

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338134/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-out-write-and-out-print)

Comment: Also, whereas `write()` supports only `int` and `String` as parameters, `print` supports all primitive datatypes.