# Issue With writing to File

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class comparing{

static ArrayList <compare> events = new ArrayList<compare>();

public static void main(String[]args){

  try{
     Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("events.txt"));
     File output = new File("chines.txt");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(output);
     PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);

     while(in.hasNext()){

        int temp = in.nextInt();
        String temptwo = in.nextLine();
        //String s = ;

        events.add(new compare(temp,temptwo));
     //System.out.println("Next word is:  " + temp);

        Collections.sort(events);
        for(int i = 0;i<events.size();i++){

           printer.write(events.get(i));
           System.out.println(events.get(i));
        }
     }
  }
  catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("Invalid file name");
  }
}
```

My code above reads from a file it sorts the data then prints it out. What I would like to do is write this sorted data to another file but I keep getting the following error:

```
  comparing.java:27: error: no suitable method found for write(compare)
               printer.write(events.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `events` to be an `ArrayList`, meaning that it contains `java.lang.Object` elements, thus `printer.write(java.lang.Object)` is what's being searched for by the compiler.

You're adding an object of your undisclosed class `compare`, so even declaring `ArrayList<compare>` wouldn't help. Hopefully your compare class has a meaningful `toString`, so that you can use `ArrayList<compare>` events, combined with `printer.write(event.toString());`

Comment: HI thank you for helping i'm new to Java how could I go about fixing this

Comment: please see my edits. Did you edit the question to include 'ArrayList<compare>'? It wasn't there in the first place

Comment: Robcco helped me see my error but thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. However, that's what the "accept answer" and "upvote" are for: Just accept his answer

Answer (score 0):

See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).
There is no `write(Object)` method. You can change it to `write(events.get(i).toString())` to convert it to a String first.

Alternatively, use `print` instead of `write` for more input options. See [write() vs print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662642/printwriter-write-vs-print-method-in-java).
It can take a object as argument and calls the `String.valueOf(obj)` method for you:

```
printer.print(events.get(i));
```

Comment: thank you very much , sorry for my messy code. If you don't mind me asking will printer.print still write to the file ?

Comment: Yes, the print methods will internally call `write`. The difference is only in how it interpets the input you give it. You can get some examples of this if you search for 'printwriter write vs print'

Comment: I just don't understand how it would work because printer isn't a static variable and if i use it inside my for loop I will get an error. I tried making in static and putting the for loop inside the while loop but it didn't work

Comment: What is the error? It shouldn't have anything to do with it being a static reference.  But don't forget to close the stream by calling `close()` on the writer when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Add  this code instead of your loop

```
           for (int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) 
            {
                printer.write(String.valueOf(events.get(i)));
                out.write(" ");
            }
```