# System.out.write() in Java-not printing the least significant of an integer value

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

This is my code:

```
class writedemo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
      int b;
      b=1;
      System.out.write(b);
      System.out.write('\n');    
    }
}
```

The output I got was the 'apl functional quad question' character(U+2370).

But this code worked:

```
class writedemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      int b;
      b='A';
      System.out.write(b);
      System.out.write('\n');    
    }
}
```

It prints the character `'A'`. Can someone please help me? Am I missing anything?

Comment: What did you expect to be printed?

Comment: Do you want to achieve, that 1 is printed to console?

Comment: Yes,I wanted 1 to be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.out.write() store and prints the ASCII value. You can use System.out.print() to show your integer value. Difference of both is given below:

```
System.out.write(65);  //will print ASCII value of 65 which is A;
System.out.print(65); // will print just 65
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a character value `'A'` to `int`, the numeric [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value is saved. According to the ASCII table the glyph `'A'` is converted to `65` as an decimal value. Here is the difference between the methods `System.out::print` and `System.out::write` which might be confusing:

- `System.out.println(b);` prints `65` because in [`System.out::print(int x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-int-) the `x` is understood as an integer:

  > Prints an integer and then terminate the line.
- `System.out.write(b);` prints `A` because in [`System.out::write(int b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write-int-) the `b` is understood as a byte:

  > Writes the specified byte to this stream. If the byte is a newline and automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.
  >
  > Note that the byte is written as given; to write a character that will be translated according to the platform's default character encoding, use the print(char) or println(char) methods.

Comment: Thanks, but when I pass the integer value '1' to write(int b). Should'nt it actually print the ASCII equivalent of it's least significant byte?

Comment: @VaibhavRanjith: Do you pass `'1'` or `1`?  - There is a big difference! If `'1'` If you pass `'1'` as a character to `write(int b)`, the character `'1'` is converted to `49` as ASCII decimal value and the method converts it back and print out the `1`. If you pass the `1` as an integer itself to the very same method, the [Start of Heading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH) character will be print because it belows under number DEC `1` in the ASCII table.

Comment: Yeah that's what I would expect too. But the code prints the U+2370 character called the app functional quad question character.

Comment: Yes, because the IDE cannot display these characters correctly and replaces them with this character.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Maantje in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662688/8458501).

> write(int) interprets the argument as a single character to be
>   printed, while print(int) converts the integer into a character
>   string. write(49) prints a "1", while print(49) prints "49".